# Lazy Loading in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I have a quick question, I want to use lazy loading in my application so searched on net and found a very good following library:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/b357e8210c2a1c96ea768b16fd0c003baef77a04

Its very simple to integrate in the code and working perfectly.

Now,my question is that if I use it in my application and release the app then can Apple have any issue on the same and can they reject my App on the basis of this?

I'm sure that many people must have used this library, so please advise me.

Comment: UITableView uses lazy loading pattern and there is no need to look for 3rd party components.

Comment: why don't you use apples' own code for lazy loading of tableview cells. Here is the link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I'm new to iphone application development and its not easy to decode me what the apple's code saying, but using the mentioned library is very easy and fast, so would prefer to use it until unless Apple does not ahve any issue in that, so want to confirm that only, anyways thansk for your reply.

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to learn iOS development so you can understand all the examples you see rather than just plugging bits of code and libraries together. Don't try to run before you can walk and you will have a much better understanding in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no Such reason that your code get rejected, just because u are using an open source library.

Yes that may be you get sued by "Owner of the library" later, if you violate the licensing conditions.

Comment: thanks for your reply,see what its license saying:Copyright (c) 2009 Olivier Poitrey <rs@dailymotion.com>
 
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights.......

Comment: Cool, go ahead and use this code. Oh, Yes mention, what Apurva said, that your code, or code you are going to use doesn't violate any apple guideline(which most of the time doesn't as it is coded by experienced fellows and they take care of this). Then your application is in AppStore in "ONE GO".. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not violating any of apple guide line, there are no chances to get your app rejected. But you should also read license agreement of third party code.